# C++ pool allocator program crashing only on console close

Tags: c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2012

I am looking at this [pool allocator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127258/simple-pool-allocator) implementation. I have actually modified it a bit and my full code is:

```
template <class T, size_t T_per_page = 200>
class PoolAllocator
{
    private:
        const size_t pool_size = T_per_page * sizeof(T);
        std::vector<T *> pools;
        size_t count;
        size_t next_pos;

        void alloc_pool() {
            next_pos = 0;
            void *temp = operator new(pool_size);
            pools.push_back(static_cast<T *>(temp));
        }
    public:
        PoolAllocator() {
            count = 0;
            alloc_pool();
        }

        void* allocate() {
            if (next_pos == T_per_page)
                alloc_pool();

            void* ret = pools.back() + next_pos;
            ++next_pos;
            ++count;
            return ret;
        }

        size_t getSize() const
        {
            return T_per_page * (pools.size() - 1) + next_pos;
        }

        size_t getCount() const
        {
            return count;
        }

        size_t getCapacity() const
        {
            return T_per_page * pools.size();
        }

        T* get(size_t index) const
        {
            if (index >= getCount()) { return NULL; }

            size_t poolIndex = index / T_per_page;
            return pools[poolIndex] + (index % T_per_page);
        }

        ~PoolAllocator() {
            std::cout << "POOL ALLOCATOR DESTRUCTOR CALLED" << std::endl;
            while (!pools.empty()) {
                T *p = pools.back();
                size_t start = T_per_page;
                if (pools.size() == 1){
                    start = next_pos;
                }

                std::cout << "start: " << start << std::endl;
                for (size_t pos = start; pos > 0; --pos)
                {
                    std::cout << "pos: " << pos << std::endl;
                    p[pos - 1].~T();
                }
                operator delete(static_cast<void *>(p));
                pools.pop_back();
            }
        }
};

template<class T>
PoolAllocator<T>& getAllocator()
{
    static PoolAllocator<T> allocator;
    return allocator;
}

class Node
{
    private:
        int id;
        std::vector<float> vertices;

    public:
        Node() : id(42)
        { 
            std::cout << "Node constructor called" << std::endl;
        }
        ~Node(){ std::cout << "Node destructor called" << std::endl; }

        void* operator new(size_t size)
        {
            std::cout << "Node operator new called" << std::endl;
            return getAllocator<Node>().allocate();
        }

        void operator delete(void*)
        {
            std::cout << "Node operator delete called" << std::endl;
        }
    };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Node* n1 = new Node();
    Node* n2 = new Node();  
    Node* n3 = new Node();
    Node* n4 = new Node();

    std::cout << "Count: " << getAllocator<Node>().getCount() << " size: " << getAllocator<Node>().getSize() << " capacity: " << getAllocator<Node>().getCapacity() << std::endl;

    while (true){}

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code in visual studio it appears to work correctly up until I close the console at which point I get an access violation error. I have tried manually calling the destructor on the allocator and it appears to work properly but I must be making a mistake somewhere. The error I get is:

[image]

Can anyone spot where I am making my mistake?

**Edit 1:**

Upon further investigation it will still crash even without the new Node lines in main. Seems to be related to getAllocator() method and how the destructor is called maybe? Or the fact that the allocator is static??

**Edit 2:**

I actually don't think it has anything to do with my allocator at all! If I try the code:

```
class Node2
{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        Node2():x(42){std::cout << "Node2 constructor called" << std::endl;};
        Node2(const Node2& other){ std::cout << "Node2 copy constructor called" << std::endl; };
        ~Node2(){ std::cout << "Node2 destructor called" << std::endl; };
};

Node2& Test(){
    static Node2 myIndex;

    return myIndex;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Test();

    while (true){}

    return 0;
}
```

It results in the same error! The plot thickens. I assumed being new to writing custom allocators that the allocator code was the issue. Still not sure why exactly this error is happening for my smaller code yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing an answer as I can't comment on the question.

I can't spot any obvious error in the last code. Are you sure you are compiling the right file and not an old unsaved version and such?

You can try to remove the line

```
while (true){}
```

And let the program just end normally.

Also, you can try to run your code in debug mode, single-stepping the instructions to find the one causing troubles.

Comment: Indeed this lead me to the solution!. By closing hitting "x" on the console while it was in the infinite loop I was loosing the ability to print. Because this happens before the destructors are called and I am trying to print in my destructors, it was causing a crash. Man what a waste of half a day trying to figure this bug out. For now on I am using your ctrl+F5 suggestion and not using an infinite loop to hold the console open. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can spot some problems with that pool allocator.

1. `PoolAllocator` owns resources, but there's neither special copy constructor nor assignment. Most likely you should declare them deleted. And provide move-constructor and move-assignment. Though not a factor in this particular example, it may protect you from absendmindedly returning an allocator by value.
2. Function `alloc_pool()` resets `next_pos` before the new chunk is allocated. An exception, if ever thrown by `operator new`, would leave the pool in an inconsistent state.
3. Likewise, an exception in `pools.push_back()` would see the new chunk leaked. I believe `std::vector<std::vector<std::byte>>` would do just right, what with modern vectors being moveable. But if you absolutely want to use a vector of raw pointers, you should reserve extra space in `pools`, then allocate new chunk, and only then call `push_back` and modify the state.
4. Constructor of PoolAllocator may throw for no good reason.
   Since `allocate()` method have to call `alloc_pool()` anyway, why calling it in the constructor? You could have a trivial noexcept constructor simply by leaving all allocation work to `allocate()`.
5. `PoolAllocator::allocate()` and `PoolAllocator::~PoolAllocator()` are not symmetric. The former returns raw memory with no initialized object, while the latter assumes there's a properly constructed object in every allocated slot. That assumption is dangerous and very fragile. Imagine, for example, that `T::T()` throws.
6. It seems that getSize() and getCount() always return the same value. Is it intended?
7. Destructor will delete `next_pos` objects in the *first* pool, `pools[0]`, and `T_per_page` objects in every other pool. But it should delete `next_pos` objects in the *last* pool.
8. You're in for wonderful bugs if `T:~T()` called from destructor of the pool ever tried to allocate another object from that very same pool. Such scenario may seem weird, but well, technically it can happen. Destructor'd better swap the current state of the pool to local variables and work on them. Repeating, if necessary.
9. That infinite loop in main() could spoil the destruction of global objects. Compiler could be smart enough to figure out that `return` is unreachable and skip the destruction part altogether.
10. `pool_size` could be a static member.

Comment: Thanks Igor the suggestions. I totally missed a lot of those bugs.